# How to make a function such that it filters based on words contained in the input

Tags: python

SO, I wanted to make it such that if an input x contains Averagefirearmsper100 then the following output shall be given

```
def correlation(x):
    if x.str.contains("Averagefirearmsper100"):
        print(corr1)
        corr1plot.show()
        if corr1 > -0.99 & corr1 < -0.4 :
            print("strong negative relation")
        elif corr1 > -0.39 & corr1 < -0.20 :
            print('weak negative relation')
        elif corr1 > -0.19 & corr1 < 0.19 :
            print('no or negligible relation')
        elif corr1 > 0.20 & corr1 <0.39 :
            print('weak positive relation')
        elif corr1 > 0.4 & corr1 < 0.99 :
            print('strong positive relation')
```

### im getting the following error,

```
AttributeError                            
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-dc3f5f5c9df1> in <module>()
----> 1 correlation("HDI")

<ipython-input-56-308ea6ff6259> in correlation(x)
      1 def correlation(x):
----> 2     if x.str.contains("Averagefirearmsper100"):
      3         print(corr1)
      4         corr1plot.show()
      5         if corr1 > -0.99 & corr1 < -0.4 :

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `x`? Please construct a [MCVE]. In particular, we need an input sample and the expected output. It must also be runnable for us to verify the error. Your current code can't be run.

Comment: From your error, I'll said that `x` is string so you only need to do `"Averagefirearmsper100" in x`

Answer (score 0):

If the input `x` is of type `str`, then the error happens because a `str` does not have an attribute named `str`.

You can try to change your code from

```
if x.str.contains("Averagefirearmsper100"):
```

to

```
if "Averagefirearmsper100" in x:
```